# How to combine prefix query with synonym filter in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using Elasticsearch 7.13 and came across an issue.

Assume that we have the following data:

```
horse
mouse
chicken
rooster
duck
cow
```

Let's assume the synonym file has the following entries (i.e. `rooster` and `chicken` are synonym with each other):

```
rooster,chicken
```

The below **MATCH** query will return both `chicken` and `rooster`.

```
"query": {
    "match": {
      "animal": "chicken"
  }
}
```

But the below **PREFIX** query will only return `chicken`, but no `rooster`.

```
"query": {
    "prefix": {
      "animal": "chic"
  }
}
```

What I wanted is for the user to enter just `chic` and Elasticsearch will return both `chicken` and `rooster`.

Is there a way to combine a **prefix** search with **synonym**?

This is in my setting:

```
"filter": {
    "synonyms_animal": {
        "type": "synonym_graph",
        "synonyms_path": "synonyms_animal.txt",
        "updateable": "true"
    }
}
```

```
"analyzer": {
    "custom_synonyms": {
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonyms_animal"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "whitespace"
    }
}
```

This is my mapping properties section:

```
"animal": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "some_custom_index_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer": "custom_synonyms"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out you cannot use search time synonym.

You have to use index time synonym for it to work.